# where to set config values in cloudera hive setup?

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am new to Cloudera quickstart. As per the requirement, we need to partition the data of large hive tables. there is cap of 100 dynamic partition in hive. We need to increase number of dynamic partitions in the configurations. I don't want to set it on the CLI everytime.

Where can i find the configuration file to update the following settings ?

```
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode  
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions  
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

Will sqoop create any problem while importing data from sql server to hive with dynamic partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Hive is configured through hive-site.xml.

On your local server, execute this command to try and find it

```
locate hive-site.xml
```